# Excel - Finding non-zero values in a row and pulling corresponding data into a table

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large sheet, a small sample of which follows the following format:

**Sample Input:**

[image]

As you can see there is a list of names followed many columns of percentages, many of them 0.  I need to find all the non-zero values and then pull all the associated headers into a table along with this data, following this format:

**Sample Output:**

[image]

I had been trying to tackle this with formulas, but I think this may require VBA, and my VBA skills are rusty to say the least. Any help on making this work would be greatly appreciated!

And if you can't make the VBA work to produce all the tables, then a formula to at least bring back all the non-zero values in each row would be greatly helpful as well. Thanks!

Comment: Your sample output is not "a table" but rather a set of tables: one for each non-header row of the input. And you can't know in advance how big each sub-table will be, so you can't reasonably write formulas in the cells, since you don't know which output rows are headers and which are data.

Comment: Understood, that is why I thought VBA may be more helpful. I think in the past I've made formulas that populate down with all values that =x in a large range. Just wondering if a lookup could be done based off the values that dont equal 0 in that particular row. The next entry could be placed to the side in another column rather than below in a another row as to not interfere with the non-zero values populating.  Would something like that be possible?

Comment: Do you need to do this once or periodically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to assume a fair amount but I tried to note where I did assume something with 'change as necessary'.

```
Sub Exporter()
Dim wsO As Worksheet, wsE As Worksheet
Dim fNameCol As Long, lNameCol As Long, deptCol As Long, comRow As Long, catRow As Long
Dim startCol As Long, endCol As Long, startRow As Long, endRow As Long
Dim workRow As Long

'error handling
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'speed improvement
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'this is the sheet with your raw data (change as necessary)
Set wsO = ActiveSheet

'put exported information onto a sheet called Export (change as necessary)
Set wsE = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Export")

'clear bold from export sheet
wsE.Cells.Font.Bold = False

'define rows/columns to work with (change as necessary)
fNameCol = 1
lNameCol = 2
deptCol = 3
comRow = 1
catRow = 2

'define start row and end row
startRow = WorksheetFunction.Match("First Name", wsO.Columns(fNameCol), 0) + 1
endRow = wsO.Cells(startRow, fNameCol).End(xlDown).Row

'define start column and end column
startCol = WorksheetFunction.Match("Company", wsO.Rows(comRow), 0) + 1
endCol = wsO.Cells(comRow, startCol).End(xlToRight).Column

'loop through all names
For x = startRow To endRow

    'increment
    workRow = workRow + 1

    'exported name
    wsE.Cells(workRow, 1) = wsO.Cells(x, lNameCol) & ", " & wsO.Cells(x, fNameCol)

    'exported headers
    workRow = workRow + 1

    With wsE.Cells(workRow, 2)
        .Value = "Company"
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With

    With wsE.Cells(workRow, 3)
        .Value = "Category"
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With

    With wsE.Cells(workRow, 4)
        .Value = "(intentional blank space)"
    End With

    With wsE.Cells(workRow, 5)
        .Value = "Department"
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With

    'increment
    workRow = workRow + 1

    'search for non-zero values
    For y = startCol To endCol

        'if not zero
        If wsO.Cells(x, y).Value > 0 Then

            'copy value and format to column A
            With wsE.Cells(workRow, 1)
                .Value = wsO.Cells(x, y).Value
                .NumberFormat = "##%"
            End With

            'copy other values
            wsE.Cells(workRow, 2).Value = wsO.Cells(comRow, y).Value
            wsE.Cells(workRow, 3).Value = wsO.Cells(catRow, y).Value
            wsE.Cells(workRow, 5).Value = wsO.Cells(x, deptCol).Value

            'increment
            workRow = workRow + 1

        End If

    Next y

Next x

'autofit columns
wsE.Columns.AutoFit

'speed improvement
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox Err.Number & vbCr & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

It worked with the sample data provided but I can't guarantee it'll work with your full workbook.